# jQuery populate radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I have this radio button:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="training" value="yes"> Yes &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="training" value="no"> No</td>
```

And I am getting a data from a database via ajax call. The training value from the database is either yes or no.

My question is, how would I populate the radio buttons based off the value from the database.

Comment: `$('input[type=radio][name=training][value=' + myValue + ']').prop('checked', true);`. Now if you want specific help, include your code...

Comment: could you please clear me that you want to set radio button based on database value is it so ?

Comment: Some browsers set chosen value to "checked".
$("input[id*='ID_OF_YOUR_RADIO']").prop('checked', 'checked');
How you obtain your DB value we don't know. This is something you would call on that input after you have found which one has to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can check radio button with value like following.

```
var valueFromDB="yes"; //assume this is your value from DB.
$('input[name=training][value=' + valueFromDB + ']').prop('checked', true);
```

Hope this will help you.